# Export large data using WhereIn and cursor in Laravel

Tags: laravel, load, export-to-csv, where-in

I have a collection of 25k rows that I get from a CSV file, which contains a URL column.

How can I perform an optimized query using the value of the URL column?

This is what i have so far:

```
public function export()
{
   $collection = FastExcel::import($file);
   $urls = $this->getData($collection);
   FastExcel::data($urls)->export('file.xlsx');
}

// generator function
public function getData( $collection )
{
   $query = MyModel::select('url', 'views')
      ->whereIn('url', $collection->pluck('url'))
      ->cursor();

   foreach ($query as $row) {
      yield $row;
   }
}
```

This works using little memory, but the query time is very high.

```
Memory usage    54 MB
Query: select `url`, `views` from `my_table` where `url` in...  297.36ms
```

I am using Laravel 9, MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Build your query with query builder ( db raw ) to get one result , then do your magic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).